# Unable to upload an image from the iOS app - "The app submitted an invalid request"

Tags: bug, edits, answers, ios-app

received a message to “see meta” after trying to upload photos to an answer I’m updating.

[image: The app submitted an invalid request. Please let us know on meta.]

This is the answer I’m trying to update with photos. 
[How can I extend the rough-in drain away from the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/177266/64464)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this question doesn't contain any detail to help us diagnose the problem. Can you please [edit] this post to indicate the exact steps to reproduce the problem you're facing? Also note that the mobile apps aren't currently being developed, so if this is a bug, it may take a long time until it gets fixed.

Comment: Try uploading the images from the desktop site on a desktop computer. Do you still get an error message, or does it work fine?

Comment: I don’t know if it’s a bug. I simply tried (3 times) to add photos to update and answer. I have posted the link and the error message. I came here as directed. Then I was dinged without explanation or solution. I have been able to post photos on another answer without incident.

Comment: No computer, just phone but as I said , I was able to upload on another answer and this question as well.

Comment: Your initial post didn't contain *any* detail about the issue you were facing. Please note that this site is just like most Q&A sites on the network: we're just users who don't know much other than the information in your post; we're not support representatives who have access to the full logs as to what you were doing. You've since edited it to include more info, and this is good; one of the downvoters has removed their vote, and you've received another upvote since.

Comment: Uploading from some other method/platform other than the iOS app will help us determine whether it's a bug in the iOS app, or some other flaw that would deny the image from any platform (that is just giving a vague message in the app).

Comment: I understand all that you’ve detailed here. The trouble is with this particular post only. I cannot make attempt on any other device as none is available. This is the first time I’ve asked for assistance with a technical issue and was only able to add the details as an edit. I appreciate your response. Thanks.

Comment: I have *no* reputation (101) on that site and I was able to upload a photo, so it's not a limit on the number of images or a problem with using a desktop browser on an Android phone. Perhaps the problem was temporary ***or*** that particular image was corrupted; try a different image. --- On another note: You wrote text ("UPDATE: I’ve literally just changed ...") **after** the links, it should have been added before them; not that it is related to *this* bug, just the proper way of making an edit. --- Try with a different image, erase that line, then try again with the image you actually want.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it the old college try.

Comment: No dice. I moved the ‘update’ above all images/links and continue to get the same error message. I tried 3 different images, all of which I was able to post elsewhere. I remain stumped 

Comment: In short: don't use the app. It's outdated and dead by all means.

Comment: The only app I’m using is this one. I’m uploading photos directly from my iPhone’s photo library using the the Stack Exchange app. I posted photos just prior and just after the “troublesome” post I’m inquiring about. The upload photos issue exists only on the post in question.

Comment: That's the app that Shadow is talking about. You should use the website instead.

Comment: M.Mat, thanks for trying. The people whom have replied are users of this website, most have been here a long time, since it's the weekend (and due to there being a list of priorities) you *might* have to wait until mid-week for an official answer (if one is forthcoming). The other suggestions (if they were unclear) is to use a Web Browser (instead of the APP, which is no longer supported) such as Firefox or Google Chrome (on your phone) to access the Stack Exchange sites. I use FF for Android (in desktop mode) with great results. Better luck next post.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I dint realize the App wasn’t supported. I will use the website instead, though it’s curious that I was able to upload on the app on different questions/answers prior to and after the fail. As I’ve stated, no laptop or computer available. I’m limited to my iPhone and this has been the only problem I’ve encountered.